# Percentage of Outliers In Artificial Data

Tags: dataset, simulation, outliers

I want to do a data simulation where the generated data had the presence of multicolinearity and outliers.

For multicolinearity: p=0, 0.5 and 0.99
Outliers Percentage : 0 %, 5% and 10%

Is 10% outliers percentage enough?

Comment: Are you generating data from a bivariate distribution. You can't generate multicollinearity with I variable.  You probably know that. The term outlier is not well defined especially for multivariate data. For univariate distributions an outlier is an observation that is far away either above or below the "center" (possibly the median) of the distribution.  For the simulation you have to say how far away from the center above or below.  I am curious as to why you want to do this.  Did you want to test diagnostics for multicollinearity and influential observations?

Comment: Why did you ask if 10% outliers is enough?

Comment: @MichaelChernickI generated data using multivariate data using Cribari-Neto and Zarkos and MacKinnon and White design. Using normal distribution. I generated so that i can see the prediction performance of ANN and Group Method of Data Handling (GMDH) which have better prediction if multicolinearity and outpiers presence in the data.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Is 10% outliers strong enough to say the simulation study is correct.

Comment: In my answer I illustrated a univariate outlier situation.  For multivariate distributions, I would need to know your definition of outlier as it is not clear what direction away from the center you consider extreme. For the multivariate normal what what dimension are you using.  I think you would need at least 3. I have no idea what the design you are referencing is.  Please explain it.  Your comment that you want to know if 10% is enough to know if the simulation is correct does not make sense. The simulation study will be correct for any mixture proportions that you want.

Comment: My answer for multicollinearity did not specify how to achieve the numbers you specified for p.  I assume p is the bivariate correlation in which case the variance of the random nose component will determine determine the correlation between X1 and X2. If that is correct a p of 0 would mean that X1 and X2 are uncorrelated and if we constructed the simulation in away that makes (Y, X1, X2)  multivariate normal X1 and X2 will be independent and there would be no trace of collinearity..

Comment: @MichaelChernick You say "For univariate distributions an outlier is an observation that is far away either above or below the "center" (possibly the median) of the distribution." . I say an outlier is an observation that is far away either above or below the "expected value" for that observation. Consider the sequence of values 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,5,. The "5" is far removed from the expected value "1"  and is clearly an "outlier" but is close to the mean/median of the distribution." This is an important distinction , in my opinion.

Comment: @irishstat In your example 5 is the sample mean and also the sample median.  It is clearly not an outlier.  I don't see how you can say that 1 is the expected value. Statistical terminology says expected value and mean are the same. I call the median in the univariate case, the center of the distribution because when there is an outlier in the data the sample mean is moved away from where it would be if the outlier were removed.  A median is less sensitive to outliers and so more represents the center of the distribution.  Also in terms of population distributions the median always exists.

Comment: On the other hand the mean does not necessarily exist (consider the Cauchy distribution).  Nevertheless mean, median and mode all represent measures of central tendency. This goes for the sample estimates as well as the population parameters. They all have drawback and this was discussed recently in a post that I contributed to.

Comment: The expected value of this series is based upon the recursive process in the history 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9, which suggests a strong pattern. The "5" is inconsistent with the process. Your comments assume no predictable pattern where mine identifies a possible pattern and computes the predicted value ""1" while the actual/errant value was a "5".

Comment: @IrishStat I think your problem is that you are dealing with time series.  This has nothing to do with time series.

Comment: The statistical term for a mean is the average. In both your examples the sample mean is 5. This is a case where the mean and the median are not good measures of center or central tendency.  People sometimes call points like 5 in this case inliers, You are either thinking about prediction in a time series or  you are trying to predict the next value in the sequence.  The order of the observation is not relevant here.

Comment: I should have stated that if it was a time ordered sequence .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give answers that will be incomplete and will revise it as as the key questions get answers.  In the univariate case if you want to consider only getting outliers from one side you can achieve this by generating a mixture of normal distributions with variance 1.  The main distribution should be given a proportion of 0.9 and 0.95 to get approximately 10% and 5% outliers respectively. The main distribution could be N(0,1) and you could make the the outlier distribution N(m,1)  Choose m>0 large enough so that the two distributions have little overlap. If you take m=4 the outlier distribution will be 4 standard deviations above the mean. So there will be practically no overlap.  If you expect outliers on both sides use a mixture of three normals, N(0,1) for the main distribution and N(-m,1) and N(m,1)for the outlier distributions where again m=4 will provide little overlap on each side. To make things symmetric take p=0.025 for both outlier distributions and p=0.95 for the main distribution to achieve 5% outliers and p=0.05 for both outlier distributions and 0.90 for the main distribution to get 10% outliers.  For the 0% outlier case you use just the N(0,1) distribution.

For a 3-D multivariate normal you can again make it a mixture of three multivariate normals  with different mean vectors and say using the same covariance matrix.  You can have the mean for the main distribution at (0,0,0) and the choice of the two outlier distributions will depend on the directions that define the outliers. The same mixture proportions as in the univariate case can be usedand you can figure out how far to separate the centers to acheive minimal overlap.

Regarding multicollinearity you can use one 3-D normal with coordinates Y, X1 and X2. Y is the dependent variable and X1 and X2 are the predictor variables. The linear model would be Y=aX1+bX2+c + e where a and b are the slope parameters for the predictor, c is the intercept and e is random noise.  To generate multicollinearity you can generate X2 and make X1= d X2.  You could use d=1.  This would make it perfectly co-linear. Add a small Gaussian noise term to make it near collinear and more practical.

Comment: I used multivariate design that you stated above Y=aX1+bX2+c + e to generate both condition multicolinear and outliers. I just want to simulate both ANN and Group Method of Data handling (GMDH) model to see the performance of both model with the present both condition.

Comment: You can generate outliers in the multiple regression case with Y the dependent variable and X1 and X2 as the dependent variable.  Contours of constant probability in 3-D are ellipses.  Define outliers in terms of X1 and X2 being far outside a specified probability contour.  Add noise to X1 or X2 or both to achieve outliers by this definition.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for notes or journal that i can used to read?